# Two matplotlib/pyplot histograms with the same axes or on the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, data-visualization, jupyter-notebook

I've got two histograms that I am trying to make that have different distributions. I would like to show then next to or on top of each other, but I am not sure how to do this with pyplot. If I plot them separately, the axes of the two plots are never the same. I am attempting to do this in an ipython notebook. Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as P
%matplotlib inline
mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*P.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = P.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
mu2, sigma2 = 250, 45
x2 = mu2 + sigma2*P.randn(10000)
n2, bins2, patches2 = P.hist(x2, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

This code creates two separate plots that are each printed as they are generated. Is it possible to save these plots rather than print them, determine what the maximum/minimum for the y and x ranges are across both plots, and then adjust the ranges of each plot so that they are comparable? I know that I can set/read the ranges with P.ylim() and P.xlim(), but this only seems to refer to the most recently created figure.

I also realize that the binning might also cause a problem, so I guess I would need to use binning that would work for both figures.

Comment: They code as you put it above generates two plots on the same figure, I am not quite sure what you are asking here

Comment: I just realized that my problem was putting the plot statement in two separate ipython code cells. It would create a plot after each cell. When I run them in the same cell, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What your asking is really not clear. I guess it lies in the fact that you don't fully understand matplotlib. So here is a quick demo. For the rest, read the doc: http://matplotlib.org/

To have different plot in one figure, you need to create a figure object with subplots in it. You need to import `matplotlib.pyplot` to have full and easy access to plotting tools from matplotlib.

Here is your modified code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline # only in a notebook

mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1, 2)
n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
mu2, sigma2 = 250, 45
x2 = mu2 + sigma2*np.random.randn(10000)
n2, bins2, patches2 = ax2.hist(x2, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

So I changed `P.randn` to `np.random.randn` since I don't import pylab anymore.

The **key line** is the following:

```
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

where we create a Figure objet called `fig` with 2 Axes object within called `ax1` and `ax2`. The Axes object are where you draw your graph. So, here we create a figure with 2 axes on a grid with 1 line and 2 rows. You could have used

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
```

and call `ax[0]` and `ax[1]`.

You can get 2 plots one above the other by calling:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

Then you can plot in a given Axe the histogram you want. They will scale automatically.

So if you want to change an axis, say the X axis, to have the same one for both, you can do for instance:

```
ax_min = min(ax1.get_xlim()[0], ax2.get_xlim()[0]) # get minimum of lower bounds 
ax_max = max(ax1.get_xlim()[1], ax2.get_xlim()[1]) # get maximum of upper bounds

ax1.set_xlim(ax_min, ax_max)
ax2.set_xlim(ax_min, ax_max)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out, but I also just found out that the two histograms are added to the same figure if I create them in the same ipython code cell.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the problem thanks to ajay's comment. My issue was that I had one ipython cell with the first plot command and a second cell with the second plot command. The inline option meant that a plot was created after each cell was run. If I put the two plot commands into one cell, it creates a single chart with both histograms.